# Force the SKAction.move to be completed - swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a Snake Game using swift and the library SpriteKit.

To control the direction of the snake, the user has to swipe on the screen. To check which was the direction of the swipe, I use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` .

Now, I have to pass the information (direction of the swipe) from the `GameViewController.swift` file to the `GameScene.swift` file. To to that, I declare a 4 items array called `movesConoller`:

```
movesController[false, false, false, false]
```

If the user swipes up, the first element of the array turns true, if he scrolls down, the second element turns true and the first one false... etc. etc.

Now, in the `GameScene.swift` file I have to say what the Snake has to do if the player moves up.
For this reason, I use 2 more variables:

```
var playerX:CGFloat = 0
var playerY:CGFloat = 0
```

and then I created this code

```
if movesController[0] == true {
   playerY += 56
}
if movesController[1] == true {
   playerY -= 56
}
if movesController[2] == true {
   playerX += 56
}
if movesController[3] == true {
   playerX -= 56
}
```

Now I create the movement

```
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y )
let endPoint = CGPoint(x: playerX + player.position.x, y: playerY + player.position.y)
let moveIt = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration:0.1)
player.run(moveIt)
```

So, every time the program is executed, the `playerX` and `playerY`variables become equal to 0. Then, based on the direction of the swipe, they are added or subtracted 56.
To move the snake I just say to the head to move from his `startPoint`to his `endPoint` in 0.1 seconds.

Another thing I added is the tail. To create it I use two arrays, `snakeX` and `snakeY`. 
To these two empty arrays (of type CGFloat) I add the previous position of the snake and then, if the score remains the same, the last element of each array is deleted. Else, the last element isn't deleted and remains in his array.

Whit this method, I make the tail growing when the snake eats an apple.

BUT the head moves 56 in 0.1seconds. This means that he makes a movement of 8 pixels at each execution. Because of that, I have to add to `snakeX` and `snakeY` the X and Y values every 7 execution of the program.

This is the problem. If the player swipes on the screen just after 7 execution of the program, the movement of the tail will be perfect. But if the player swipes before the 7 execution, there will be a problem. Let's suppose the snake is moving right and the player swipes up when the program is at its 4th execution.

```
//snakeX and snakeY values before the swipe
snakeX[168, 112, 56, 0] //all this numbers are multiple of 56
snakeY[224, 224, 224, 224] //the snake is moving right, the Y value doesn't change.

//snakeX and snakeY values after the swipe
snakeX[168 ,112 ,56 , 0] 
snakeY[248, 224, 224, 224] //look at the first element
```

248 is not a multiple of 56. The snake moved Up at the 4th execution, after 3 execution his position will be added to the arrays. But in 3 execution he had moved of 24pixel.
Because of that, I'll get this bug

[image]

as you can see, the tail doesn't make a perfect corner.

The snake head doesn't complete his movement of 56 pixels. When I swipe, it leaves his movement and starts another one. Is there a way I can tell the head to always complete his movement before doing another one?

Comment: You are not allowing your last action to complete before firing the next move, use some kind of queue that fires the next move when the previous move is complete.  Run has a completion handler you can tap into

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of trying to use a pixel-based approach to what's basically a grid-based game, but maybe something like this will work...

Make a variable controlling whether movement is allowed:

```swift
var moveAllowed = true
```

Guard your movement code with that variable:

```swift
if moveAllowed {
  if movesController[0] == true {
    playerY += 56
  }
  ...
}
```

When you schedule the movement action, toggle `moveAllowed`, and add a completion handler to toggle it back after the action finishes:

```swift
...
moveAllowed = false
let moveIt = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration:0.1)
player.run(moveIt) { self.moveAllowed = true }
```

(The `self.moveAllowed` might be just `moveAllowed` depending on how you have things structured, but I can't tell from your fragments.)

Edit: I just realized that maybe you're setting `snakeX` and `snakeY` based on `player.position`.  It's not really clear.  In any case, then you'd use the same idea but copying from `player.position` only when `moveAllowed` is `true`.  Basically that variable is telling you if the action is still running or not.